# Can I add a second SODIMM to a Thinkpad Lenovo P1 with the Xeon processor?

Tags: memory, thinkpad, xeon

The [Thinkpad Lenovo P1 with the Xeon processor (part number 20MDCTO1WW)](https://www.lenovo.com/gb/en/laptops/thinkpad/p-series/ThinkPad-P1/p/20MDCTO1WWENGB2/customize?) comes with these RAM options:

- 8GB DDR4 2666MHz SODIMM
- 8GB DDR4 2666MHz ECC SODIMM
- 16GB DDR4 2666MHz SODIMM
- 16GB(8+8) DDR4 2666MHz SODIMM
- 16GB DDR4 2666MHz ECC SODIMM
- 16GB(8+8) DDR4 2666MHz ECC SODIMM
- 32GB(16+16) DDR4 2666MHz SODIMM
- 32GB DDR4 2666MHz SODIMM
- 32GB(16+16) DDR4 2666MHz ECC SODIMM
- 64GB(32+32) DDR4 2666MHz SODIMM

The fact that there are 8+8, 16+16 and so on options present, makes me believe it has two slots for RAM. I'm thinking of getting the one with 16GB DDR4 2666MHz ECC SODIMM; Would I be able in the future to upgrade to 32GB by adding a second SODIMM?

My question comes from my vague recollection that once upon a time you needed to get matched pairs of ram sticks and they would work individually but not (or not very well) with other non-matched sticks.

Comment: "P1" is a marketing name, not a true model number. Please obtain that necessary information from https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht077589 or from the serial number plate underneath the ThinkPad, and when you have it, come back her and click on `edit` above at left to add it to your original question.

Comment: @K7AAY: I see only one P1 in the list: P1 (Type 20MD, 20ME) Laptop (ThinkPad). I haven't bought the P1 yet, so, I can't search by serial number.

Comment: @K7AAY: I gave you all the information Lenovo shares about the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The [manual for the Lenovo 20MDCTO1WWENGB2](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/x1p1_x1_extreme_hmm_en.pdf) does show two DIMM slots for memory modules, and it states on pp. 65-66 memory modules are a user-changeable item.

Different PC designs require different memory configurations for optimal performance; one, two, three, or four memory modules can be called for.

[image: Page 61 of the aforementioned manual]